# Using a Kit of RAMs vs. using two RAMs of same specification and manufacturer

Tags: memory

I want to use Corsair Vengeance 2x4GB Kit but its a little costlier than buying two seperate 4GBs of same specifications.
[1600MHz, DDR3L, Low Voltage, Latency 9]
Will using two such seperate rams have any different effects than using the kit?

Comment: The memory is identical just different part numbers to track supply

Comment: If you plan on using them in Dual-Channel mode, then you would be assured of matching modules with a kit.

Answer (score 1):

If you buy two of the same product from the same place at the same time it will be fine and will perform identically to a "kit". In most cases they will be from the same batch and be effectively identical.

However bear in mind the advantage of kits is more from a support point of view - if one module fails several years down the line, if you bought separate modules the replacement chip may not be identical to the others, whereas with a kit they will replace all modules (including non-faulty modules) with matching pairs/sets.

Even that said, the likelihood of tangible differences between "mismatched" sets of RAM with the same basic specs (clock rate and latency) is small.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's a standard there should be no difference in performance if you use two different RAMs with the same specifications.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with qasdfdsaq that there is an advantage to buying the kit because the modules chips come from the same manufacturing batch and as such the "limited lifetime" warranty offers more protection down the road.  However, two modules of the same part number purchased separately would offer identical performance.  In either case, you should check the motherboard manufacturers website for the Qualified Vendor's List (QVL) for that specific board to ensure that the memory modules have been validated.  If those modules are not on the list they may still work but you always run the risk that they will not.